# Don't know why this small shell script wont work

Tags: bash, ubuntu-10.04, shell

I'm trying to make a small script to start up gunicorn for a python website I'm making. I have modified the script found at https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/gunicorn_rc slightly. Here's my version.

```
#!/bin/sh

GUNICORN=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
ROOT=/srv/mobile-site/app
PID=/var/run/gunicorn.pid

APP=mobilecms:app

if [ -f $PID ]; then rm $PID fi        

cd $ROOT
exec $GUNICORN -b 127.0.0.1:8080 -w 8 -k gevent --pidfile=$PID $APP
```

When I try to run the script though, it shows this error

```
/etc/init.d/gunicorn: 13: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a semi-colon between `rm $PID` and `fi`. Like this:

```
if [ -f $PID ]; then rm $PID; fi
```

The semi-colons are essentially shorthand so you can put this small if statement on a single line. Without them it would look like this:

```
if [ -f $PID ]
then
    rm $PID
fi
```